# When is TCP option SO_LINGER (0) required?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, setsockopt, so-linger

I think I understand the formal meaning of the option. In some legacy code I'm handling now, the option is used. The customer complains about RST as response to FIN from its side on connection close from its side.

I am not sure I can remove it safely, since I don't understand when it should be used.

Can you please give an example of when the option would be required?

Comment: You should remove it. It shouldn't be used in production code. The only time I ever saw it used was as the result of an invalid benchmark.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The typical reason to set a `SO_LINGER` timeout of zero is to avoid large numbers of connections sitting in the `TIME_WAIT` state, tying up all the available resources on a server.

When a TCP connection is closed cleanly, the end that initiated the close ("active close") ends up with the connection sitting in `TIME_WAIT` for several minutes.  So if your protocol is one where the *server* initiates the connection close, and involves very large numbers of short-lived connections, then it might be susceptible to this problem.

This isn't a good idea, though - `TIME_WAIT` exists for a reason (to ensure that stray packets from old connections don't interfere with new connections).  It's a better idea to redesign your protocol to one where the client initiates the connection close, if possible.

Comment: I totally agree. I have seen a monitoring application which was initiating many (a few thousands short lived connections every X seconds), and it had probem to scale bigger (a thousand connection more). I don't know why, but the applicatoin was non responsive. Someone suggested the SO_LINGER = true, TIME_WAIT = 0 to free OS resources quickly, and after short investigation we did try this solution with very good results. The TIME_WAIT is no longer a problem for this app.

Comment: I disagree. An application level protocol sitting on top of TCP should be designed in such a way that the client always initiates the connection close. That way, the `TIME_WAIT` will sit at the client doing no harm. Remember as it says in "UNIX Network Programming" third edition (Stevens et al) page 203: "The TIME_WAIT state is your friend and is there to help us. Instead of trying to avoid the state, we should understand it (Section 2.7)."

Comment: What if a client wants to open 4000 connections every 30 seconds (this monitoring application is a client! because it initiates connection)?
Yes we can redesing the application, add some local agents in the infrastructure, change the model to push. But if we already have such an application and it grows, then we can make it work by tuning twe linger. You change one param, and you suddenly have working application, without investing a budget to implement new architecture.

Comment: @bartosz.r: The classic solution would be to assign multiple IP addresses to the machine running the monitoring application, giving it more local addresses to use.

Comment: @caf I have never heard about this. But then you have to repeat that multi IP assignemtn on every machine you move, every time you move (when upgrading hardware, OS...). This is another configuration to manage, and if you set Linger, this is someting you own in your applications config.

Comment: @bartosz.r: I only saying that using SO_LINGER with timeout 0 should really be a last resort. Again, in "UNIX Network Programming" third edition (Stevens et al) page 203 it also says that you risk data corruption. Consider reading RFC 1337 where you can see why TIME_WAIT is your friend.

Comment: @mgd you made a good point. One have to know all of this and test this before using in the wild. I can only say that in my situation there are quick and short transmissions so random Seq numbers in TCP/IP (as described in the RFC 1337) should take care about old packets. At least I was not able to see any corruption yet.

Comment: Turning off SO_LINGER does not avoid large numbers of connections sitting in the TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: @JingguoYao Correct. Setting it on with zero timeout does that. It's an execrable practice to be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @caf No, the classic solution would be a connection pool, as seen in every heavy-duty TCP API, for example HTTP 1.1.

Comment: I agree that SO_LINGER with timeout 0 is a last resort, but I deem it necessary for HTTP servers (or other workarounds instead of SO_LINGER). HTTP is a protocol with short-lived connections where *the server* initiates the close of the connection. A "high-performance" HTTP server is only possible if the server forgets about the connection immediately once close() has been called. Also close() must be non-blocking for a single-threaded HTTP server, so setting a linger time out larger than zero is not viable.

Answer (score 244):

For my suggestion, please read the last section: **“When to use SO_LINGER with timeout 0”**.

Before we come to that a little lecture about:

- Normal TCP termination
- `TIME_WAIT`
- `FIN`, `ACK` and `RST`

### Normal TCP termination

The normal TCP termination sequence looks like this (simplified):

We have two peers: A and B

1. A calls `close()`

- A sends `FIN` to B
- A goes into `FIN_WAIT_1` state

1. B receives `FIN`

- B sends `ACK` to A
- B goes into `CLOSE_WAIT` state

1. A receives `ACK`

- A goes into `FIN_WAIT_2` state

1. B calls `close()`

- B sends `FIN` to A
- B goes into `LAST_ACK` state

1. A receives `FIN`

- A sends `ACK` to B
- A goes into `TIME_WAIT` state

1. B receives `ACK`

- B goes to `CLOSED` state – i.e. is removed from the socket tables

### TIME_WAIT

So the peer that initiates the termination – i.e. calls `close()` first – will end up in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

To understand why the `TIME_WAIT` state is our friend, please read section 2.7 in "UNIX Network Programming" third edition by Stevens et al (page 43).

However, it can be a problem with lots of sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state on a server as it could eventually prevent new connections from being accepted.

To work around this problem, I have seen many suggesting to set the SO_LINGER socket option with timeout 0 before calling `close()`. However, this is a bad solution as it causes the TCP connection to be terminated with an error.

Instead, design your application protocol so the connection termination is always initiated from the client side. If the client always knows when it has read all remaining data it can initiate the termination sequence. As an example, a browser knows from the `Content-Length` HTTP header when it has read all data and can initiate the close. (I know that in HTTP 1.1 it will keep it open for a while for a possible reuse, and then close it.)

If the server needs to close the connection, design the application protocol so the server asks the client to call `close()`.

### When to use SO_LINGER with timeout 0

Again, according to "UNIX Network Programming" third edition page 202-203, setting `SO_LINGER` with timeout 0 prior to calling `close()` will cause the normal termination sequence *not* to be initiated.

Instead, the peer setting this option and calling `close()` will send a `RST` (connection reset) which indicates an error condition and this is how it will be perceived at the other end. You will typically see errors like "Connection reset by peer".

Therefore, in the normal situation it is a really bad idea to set `SO_LINGER` with timeout 0 prior to calling `close()` – from now on called *abortive close* – in a server application.

However, certain situation warrants doing so anyway:

- If a client of your server application misbehaves (times out, returns invalid data, etc.) an abortive close makes sense to avoid being stuck in `CLOSE_WAIT` or ending up in the `TIME_WAIT` state.
- If you must restart your server application which currently has thousands of client connections you might consider setting this socket option to avoid thousands of server sockets in `TIME_WAIT` (when calling `close()` from the server end) as this might prevent the server from getting available ports for new client connections after being restarted.
- On page 202 in the aforementioned book it specifically says: "There are certain circumstances which warrant using this feature to send an abortive close. One example is an RS-232 terminal server, which might hang forever in `CLOSE_WAIT` trying to deliver data to a stuck terminal port, but would properly reset the stuck port if it got an `RST` to discard the pending data."

I would recommend [this](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) long article which I believe gives a very good answer to your question.

Comment: `TIME_WAIT` is a friend only when it doesn't start to cause problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803566/what-is-the-cost-of-many-time-wait-on-the-server-side

Comment: so what if you are writing a web server?  how do you "tell the client to initiate a close"?

Comment: @ShaunNeal you obviously don't. But a well written client / browser will initiate the close. If the client is not well-behaving, luckily we have TIME_WAIT assassination to ensure we do not run out of socket descriptors and ephemeral ports.

Answer (score 18):

When linger is on but the timeout is zero the TCP stack doesn't wait for pending data to be sent before closing the connection. Data could be lost due to this but by setting linger this way you're accepting this and asking that the connection be reset straight away rather than closed gracefully. This causes an RST to be sent rather than the usual FIN.

Thanks to EJP for his comment, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Comment: I understand this. what I'm asking is for "realistic" example when we would like to use hard reset.

Comment: Whenever you want to abort a connection; so if your protocol fails validation and you have a client talking rubbish at you all of a sudden you'd abort the connection with an RST, etc.

Comment: You're confusing a zero linger timeout with linger off. Linger off means that close() doesn't block. Linger on with a positive timeout means that close() blocks for up to the timeout. Linger on with a zero timeout causes RST, and this is what the question is about.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'll adjust the answer to correct my terminology.

Answer (score 8):

Whether you can remove the linger in your code safely or not depends on the type of your application: is it a „client“ (opening TCP connections and actively closing it first) or is it a „server“ (listening to a TCP open and closing it after the other side initiated the close)?

If your application has the flavor of a „client“ (closing first) AND you initiate & close a huge number of connections to different servers (e.g. when your app is a monitoring app supervising the reachability of a huge number of different servers) your app has the problem that all your client connections are stuck in TIME_WAIT state. Then, I would recommend to shorten the timeout to a smaller value than the default to still shutdown gracefully but free up the client connections resources earlier. I would not set the timeout to 0, as 0 does not shutdown gracefully with FIN but abortive with RST.

If your application has the flavor of a „client“ and has to fetch a huge amount of small files from the same server, you should not initiate a new TCP connection per file and end up in a huge amount of client connections in TIME_WAIT, but keep the connection open and fetch all data over the same connection. Linger option can and should be removed.

If your application is a „server“ (close second as reaction to peer‘s close), on close() your connection is shutdown gracefully and resources are freed up as you don‘t enter TIME_WAIT state. Linger should not be used. But if your sever app has a supervisory process detecting inactive open connections idleing for a long time („long“ is to be defined) you can shutdown this inactive connection from your side - see it as kind of error handling - with an abortive shutdown. This is done by setting linger timeout to 0. close() will then send a RST to the client, telling him that you are angry :-)

Answer (score 3):

I just saw that in the [websockets RFC (RFC 6455)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-7.1.1), it explicitly states that the *server* should call `close()` on the TCP socket first(!)

I was in awe, as I hold the answer/posts by @mgd in this thread as de facto, and the RFC clearly goes against that. But, perhaps this would be a case where setting a linger time of 0 would be acceptable.

> The underlying TCP connection, in most normal cases, SHOULD be closed
> first by the server, so that it holds the TIME_WAIT state and not the
> client

I'm very interested to hear any thoughts/insight on this.

Answer (score 1):

In servers, you may like to send `RST` instead of `FIN` when disconnecting misbehaving clients. That skips `FIN-WAIT` followed by `TIME-WAIT` socket states in the server, which prevents from depleting server resources, and, hence, protects from this kind of denial-of-service attack.

Answer (score 1):

I like Maxim's observation that DOS attacks can exhaust server resources. It also happens without an actually malicious adversary.

Some servers have to deal with the 'unintentional DOS attack' which occurs when the client app has a bug with connection leak, where they keep creating a new connection for every new command they send to your server. And then perhaps eventually closing their connections if they hit GC pressure, or perhaps the connections eventually time out.

Another scenario is when 'all clients have the same TCP address' scenario. Then client connections are distinguishable only by port numbers (if they connect to a single server). And if clients start rapidly cycling opening/closing connections for any reason they can exhaust the (client addr+port, server IP+port) tuple-space.

So I think servers may be best advised to switch to the Linger-Zero strategy when they see a high number of sockets in the TIME_WAIT state - although it doesn't fix the client behavior, it might reduce the impact.

Answer (score 0):

The listen socket on a server can use linger with time 0 to have access to binding back to the socket immediately and to reset any clients whose connections are not yet finished connecting.  TIME_WAIT is something that is only interesting when you have a multi-path network and can end up with miss-ordered packets or otherwise are dealing with odd network packet ordering/arrival-timing.