# Nonzero [error] code on gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, docker, debian, gnupg

I am getting this message on building a Debian:stretch-slim Docker image with Python 3.7.7:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex [...]'
[...] returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I think it's a GPG or a networking issue.

Any tips? Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Following the [recommendation](https://gitlab.lsonline.fr/docker/ghost/-/issues/1) from Laurent Sittler, the solution was on adding options to the gpg servers.

Find this line in the Dockerfile:

```
&& gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
```

and replace it with this block:

```
&& ( \
  gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
    || gpg --batch --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
    || gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$GPG_KEY" \
) \
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: Any change in the code has no effect. You need to run your code again until it works (or you add more download locations to go through in an if-statement so that the chance is less that you do not catch a download, see the other answer of this thread.)**

I just leave the following old part here as a proof that any placebo code changes did not help me (therefore in *italics*), it was random and it strangely appeared at every first run, while at the second, it usually worked.

---

*Run*

```
sudo apt-get update
```

*before you run*

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

*And if you have an "echo" line before that, run *another* `sudo apt-get update` even before that:*

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN sh -c 'echo "..." > /etc/...'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-key adv ...
```

*By this, I got rid of the similar error "Cannot assign requested address":*

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Up2U8vHXpt/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
ERROR: Service 'listener' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

***Most likely: server is just busy, try again***

*This could be a placebo, though, since [this answer to the same error, but in another context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7654521/11154841) says that this can appear when the address is just busy. Which would mean: if you have this error, just try again, and `sudo apt-get update` might not change anything, then. That sounds most likely.*