# How can I block this code with Net::HTTP in ruby?

Tags: ruby, block, open-uri

Here is a URL

```
http://192.168.1.2:1218/?name=verify_code_string_queue&opt=get&auth=verify_code_string_queue
```

It will return a string or a status code like SQS_GET_END

Now I need to break the loop when the url return a string,or keep blocking.

Here is my code

```
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
loop do
  codeText = open("http://192.168.1.2:1218/?name=verify_code_string_queue&opt=get&auth=verify_code_string_queue") do |repo|
    repo.read
  end
  if codeText != "SQS_GET_END"
    break
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work,output cannot assign requested address - connect(2) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL).
Please tell me how to solve it,thanks

Comment: If its not the host you are working on, is 192.168.1.2 reachable from your host?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Do you want to know why you get the EADDRNOTAVAIL error, or do you want to 'catch' the error and continue the loop?

Comment: Anand,I can reach 192.168.1.2 certainly.

Comment: rdvdijk,I want to know the reason why I get EADDRNOTAVAIL error.

Comment: Check this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886506/why-would-connect-give-eaddrnotavail

Comment: yeah,I checked the url you gave me,but it looks useless for me,thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing too many requests in a short time. This will result in the `Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL` error. You can add a `sleep` within the loop, to limit the number of requests you make.

Something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
loop do
  codeText = open("http://192.168.1.2:1218/?name=verify_code_string_queue&opt=get&auth=verify_code_string_queue") do |repo|
    repo.read
  end
  if codeText != "SQS_GET_END"
    break
  end
  sleep 1 # <= sleep for one second
end
```