# Write HTTP trailer headers manually

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse, http-error

This question was motivated by the answers here:
[What to do with errors when streaming the body of an Http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305203/what-to-do-with-errors-when-streaming-the-body-of-an-http-request)

In this case, I have already written a HTTP 200 OK header, then I need to amend this if there is an error, by writing a trail header that says there was an error *after* writing a success header.

I have this Node.js code:

```
const writeResponse = function(file: string, socket: Socket){

   socket.write([
    'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
    'Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Encoding: UTF-8',
    'Accept-Ranges: bytes',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
   ].join('\n') + '\n\n');
        
  getStream(file)
    .pipe(socket)  
    .once('error', function (e: any) {

        // there was an error
        // how can I write trail headers here ?

        s.write('some bad shit happened\n')

    });

}
```

how do I write a useful trail header to the response that can be displayed well by the browser?

I think this is the relevant spec for trail headers:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.40

I think they should be called "trailing headers", but whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:

> I think this is the relevant spec for trail headers: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.40

RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). The current spec for trailers is [RFC 7230 § 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1.2).

Secondly:

> `].join('\n') + '\n\n'`

Lines in HTTP message framing are terminated with `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Thirdly:

> `Content-Encoding: UTF-8`

`Content-Encoding` is for [content codings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.2) (like `gzip`), not charsets (like UTF-8). You probably don’t need to indicate charset separately from `Content-Type`.

And lastly:

> how do I write a useful trail header to the response that can be displayed well by the browser?

You don’t. Mainstream Web browsers do not care about trailers.

See also (by the same user?): [How to write malformed HTTP response to “guarantee” something akin to HTTP 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299300/how-to-write-malformed-http-response-to-guarantee-something-akin-to-http-500)

Comment: ok thanks, so how do I tell the browser that the response is actually a 500 after I have written a header saying it's a 200? that would happen if reading the file went awry as I hopefully explained well in the question.

Comment: That depends on which browser, what kind of file, and what it’s requested for. Judging by `Content-Type` in your question, you might be trying to prevent execution of a `<script src/>`. Then see [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299300/) — no. 1 seems to do the trick, at least in Chromium. Otherwise, ask a separate question with specifics.

Comment: The charset goes into the content type, semicolon separated. e.g. "application/json;charset=utf-8"

Comment: @StefanSteiger Only if the media type defines such a parameter. In particular, `application/json` doesn’t — see [RFC 8259 § 11](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-11) (although some applications might support it anyway).