# Node.js, streams, files and error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, busboy

## Questions

1. How do you handle errors gracefully with streams? My code is becoming really ugly and adding `.on('error', () => …)` after every `.pipe(…)` is pain in neck. Is there another way? I read about NodeJS `domain` but it’s deprecated.
2. How do you handle errors if they occur somewhere in the middle of the stream? In my case, by that time *some* of the transformed content has already been transferred back to the user.

## My use case is:

1. User uploads a text file through a typical multipart `<form>`.
2. That file is then transformed on the fly using streams.
3. The result, which is a stream, is piped back to the user and download is triggered.

To put it shortly: You add a file, submit the form, and you get a transformed file back.

## Code example

The following code uses express for handling HTTP requests and busboy for handling file upload:

```js
export default Router()
  .get('/', renderPage)
  .post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })

    const parser = myParser()

    const transformer = myTransformer()

    busboy.on('file', (_fieldname, file, filename) => {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${filename}`)

      file
        .pipe(parser)
        .on('error', err => errorHandler(err, req, res))
        .pipe(transformer)
        .on('error', err => errorHandler(err, req, res))
        .pipe(res)
        .on('error', err => errorHandler(err, req, res))
    })
      .on('error', err => errorHandler(err, req, res))

    req.pipe(busboy)
      .on('error', err => errorHandler(err, req, res))
  })
```

Comment: Can't you have just one `.on('error', ...)` at the end of your pipe chain?

Comment: What to do when an errors occurs in the middle of a data transfer are always application specific and often require appropriate error handling on the other end too.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand that. I was wondering what's the common/best way to tell the client that an error occured at this point. Headers are already sent, it's too late for `5xx` status code.

Comment: If that's your question, then please edit your question to state it more succinctly as that.  That's not what I got from reading your question.

Comment: Perhaps this: [What to do with errors when streaming the body of an Http request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305631/816620).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [`pump`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pump). Seems like it might help with your issues.