# Abort streaming servlet response

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

I'm streaming response of unknown size to client from a servlet (really a Spring Boot controller but it shouldn't matter).

I force sending headers early by calling `flush()` so that the client (browser) can properly show that the download is started.

What should I do if an error happens in the middle of the stream?
Right now client simply gets part of the file and has no idea it's bad.

According to [What to do with errors when streaming the body of an Http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305203/what-to-do-with-errors-when-streaming-the-body-of-an-http-request) I should to TCP RST on Socket or write some garbage that is not a valid chunked encoded data.

Unfortunately I have not found a way of accessing underlying socket nor can I write malformed response - `ServletResponse#getOutputStream` does chunking internally and I couldn't find a way of bypassing that either.

Comment: Note this seems to be a Spring Boot bug / Tomcat limitation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27624. Plain Tomcat works and so does Spring Boot with Jetty. Still it would be nice to have some sort of workable workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/fa0f2567aae91a13137094ebcdb74d72b8222f3b

And is available since Tomcat to 10.1.0.