# Why does SenchaCmd think that port 1841 is already in use when it's not?

Tags: java, linux, port, sencha-cmd

When I run `sencha app watch` and then after some time I exit it and start it again, I get a warning that port 1841 is already in use and then it just uses a random port because of that.

> Port 1841 already in use.  Using dynamic port instead.

No matter how often I kill and restart that command, it refuses to take port 1841... until about 1 minute has passes since I killed it the first time. Then it will happily take port 1841 again (until I exit it the next time...).

The weird thing is that the port is not actually in use. During that one minute time frame I can just start anything else on that port. An http server for instance `http-server -p 1841` works just fine. But when I exit the http-server and try another `sencha app watch` within the time frame, it claims the port is still in in use...

`lsof` doesn't find anything blocking the port either:

```
# lsof -ti:1841 -sTCP:LISTEN | xargs kill
kill: not enough arguments
```

Running `sencha app watch --port 1841` instead of `sencha app watch` made no difference.

So I decompiled sencha.jar using Procyon and found this:

```
if (this._port > 0 && !NetworkUtil.isPortAvailable(this._port)) {
    WebServerTask._logger.warn("Port {} already in use.  Using dynamic port instead.", (Object)this._port);
    this._port = 0;
}
```

`isPortAvailable`:

```
public static synchronized boolean isPortAvailable(final int port) {
    return _isPortAvailable(port, "127.0.0.1");
}
```

`_isPortAvailable`:

```
private static boolean _isPortAvailable(final int port, final String address) {
    return _socketChannelPortAvailable(port, address) && _serverSocketPortAvailable(port, address);
}
```

`_serverSocketPortAvailable`:

```
private static boolean _serverSocketPortAvailable(final int p, final String address) {
    ServerSocket srv = null;
    try {
        srv = new ServerSocket();
        srv.setReuseAddress(false);
        if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(address)) {
            srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(address, p));
        }
        else {
            srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(p));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex2) {
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        if (srv != null) {
            try {
                srv.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw BasicException.raise(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`_socketChannelPortAvailable with 2 parameters`:

```
private static boolean _socketChannelPortAvailable(final int p, final String address) {
    return _socketChannelPortAvailable(p, address, true);
}
```

`_socketChannelPortAvailable with 3 parameters`:

```
private static boolean _socketChannelPortAvailable(final int p, final String address, final boolean reuseAddr) {
    ServerSocketChannel srv = null;
    try {
        srv = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        if (!reuseAddr) {
            srv.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, false);
        }
        if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(address)) {
            srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(address, p));
        }
        else {
            srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(p));
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        if (srv != null) {
            try {
                srv.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else like `ServerSocket`, `ServerSocketChannel`, `InetSocketAddress` and `StandardSocketOptions` seems to come from Java standard libraries:

```
import java.net.StandardSocketOptions;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
```

But it all looks like it should work to me.
Any ideas what is going wrong here?

My SenchaCmd version is 6.5.3.6 btw and I'm on Linux.

**Edit**:

Is it possible that changing

```
if (!reuseAddr) {
    srv.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, false);
}
```

to

```
srv.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, reuseAddr);
```

would solve the problem?

Comment: Most probably there was a connection to the port 1841 before the application was killed and the port is in CLOSED_WAIT state. When lsof did not find anything try `netstat -an|grep 1841` and you will probably see the port in CLOSE_WAIT state.

Comment: You are likely in TCP's close wait state as @Zaboj said. Wait 2 minutes before starting the server again. Or, use the Sencha equivalent to [`SO_REUSEADDR`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24194961/608639). Also, Systemd may be holding the socket open waiting to fast-start a server.

Comment: @ZabojCampula It returns `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53618         127.0.0.1:1841          TIME_WAIT`.

Comment: @jwww In the code above `srv.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, false)` is never executed because `reuseAddr` is true. Is that the problem?

Comment: `srv.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);` would help I think.