# Unable to reuse port when forcibly killing and re-spawning a TCP Socket application

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have an application that acts as a watchdog for another application. The duty of the watchdog is to monitor the host application existence and respawn it whenever it dies.

Below is the socket code:

```
sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sock < 0) { 
    return (-1);
}

int optval = 1;
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = SOC_READ_TIMEOUT;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*) &tv, sizeof(tv));

tv.tv_sec = SOC_READ_TIMEOUT;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char*) &tv, sizeof(tv));
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (int*) &optval,
        sizeof(int));

name.sin_family = AF_INET;
name.sin_port = htons(port);
name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
if (bind(sock, (sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name)) < 0) {
    close(sock);
    return (-1);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that whenever I kill the host application instance. The new instance gives an error "Cannot assign requested address". I believe this is occurring because the Raspbian OS doesn't support SO_REUSEPORT.

Is there any way, I can work this out? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Maybe look at SO_LINGER - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817901/410767)

Comment: Wait a few minutes, then try again.

Comment: Thanks, Tony, and super. Seems like the host application had multiple instances spawned by the watchdog process and that's why the issue was occurring. Have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Tony, and super. Seems like the host application had multiple instances spawned by the watchdog process and that's why the issue was occurring. Have resolved it.