# Kill local TCP connection in LINUX

Tags: linux, localhost

So I am working on a basic client/server school project. The server is running on port 10'000. The problem is whenever I manually close the server (CTRL+C) the local TCP connection on port 10'000 stays alive for a minute or so. It gets into a "*TIME_WAIT*" state. Is there any way I can kill the connection right away and start using it directly? Linux btw.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is TCP option SO\_LINGER (0) required?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3757289/608639), [How do I use setsockopt(SO\_REUSEADDR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24194961/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that undestand you correctly. Try `fuser -k 10000/tcp` it should help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use setsockopt() function with SO_REUSEADDR option. It should allow you to bind to the same address and port of application which you have just terminated.

Here is example of using SO_REUSEADDR:
[How do I use setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194961/how-do-i-use-setsockoptso-reuseaddr)