# How to resolve "address already in use" when a socket is not closed properly?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

On linux (Ubuntu 19.x)

I get an "address already in use" even if a port is free in some situations (e.g. TCP listener that wasn't closed properly).

This happens if I e.g. kill a process with fuser.

The address is released after an arbitrary amount of time but this wait is seriously hampering me.

Is there any way to just "force free" an address ?

Comment: You can enable `SO_REUSEADDR` with `setsockopt(2)` to allow your program to bind to the port immediately. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194961/how-do-i-use-setsockoptso-reuseaddr)

Answer (score -1):

Try to kill the orphaned processes if your program spawned any while it's running. Or find out which process is still holding the internet port, and `kill` it.

```
sudo lsof -i :port
```

Comment: That is neither necessary nor sufficient.