# How to re-bind local socket after it was closed?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix-socket

If a unix socket is bound to a path, `listen()`s and do some work, after which it is closed, the socket "file" remains in the filesystem. But if I try to `connect()` to that path, I get

```
Connect errno:111
Connection refused
```

So what is left after the "artifact"? It is still an `inode` on filesystem (I can see it with `ls`), but it is not bound, not listening, and I cannot `cat` it, otherwise I get

```
cat: /tmp/unix.str: No such device or address
```

So what remains from the `inode`? And how can I make that "artifact" once more alive, bound and listening socket (*without* removing it, and creating fresh new socket with that path)?

1. What is the purpose of "dead" local socket (why is it not remove after it was closed, when there is no usage with it anymore)?
2. how can I revive the "dead" socket? (the main question)
3. who is responsible for error `connection refused`? not being `bind()`ed or not `listen()`ing?

Answer (score -1):

You get "connection refused" when attempting to connect because nothing is listening on that local socket.  It's the same as if you tried to make a connection to a TCP socket if nothing was listening on that port number.

Once the program that opened the socket is closed, it is the responsibility of that process to remove the file with `unlink`.  The [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) states:

> Binding to a socket with a filename creates a socket in the
> filesystem that must be deleted by the caller when it is no
> longer needed (using unlink(2)).  The usual UNIX close-behind
> semantics apply; the socket can be unlinked at any time and will
> be finally removed from the filesystem when the last reference to
> it is closed.

This of course could be a problem if the program crashes unexpectedly, so you could get around this by additionally using a lock file.

Another alternative is to use an **abstract socket address**.  This is done by setting the first byte of `sun_path` in `sockaddr_un` to 0 and the remaining bytes to a null terminated string specifying the socket name.  For example:

```
struct sockaddr_un sun;
sun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
sun.sun_path[0] = 0;
strcpy(sun.sunpath + 1, "mysocketname");
```

This gives you a named socket without a corresponding socket file in the filesystem.  This socket will automatically go away once the socket descriptor is closed, so another socket may then be opened with that name.

Comment: I cannot re-bind the local socket, if it exists (`Bind errno:98; Address already in use`), so I have to first `unlink()`, the old (dead) socket, after which I can re-bind and listen to that path again. But that is the question, what is the purpose of the "dead" socket, and how can I revive the dead socket (make it listening again), without `unlink()`

Comment: @milanHrabos  See my edit.  It must be `unlink`'ed.

Comment: So the abstract socket is not created as `inode` on a filesystem? If no, how could be "abstract" (not being physically on filesystem) referenced? How is its data buffered? if it is not a regular inode?

Comment: @milanHrabos A socket descriptor in the filesystem isn't an actual file that contains buffered data.  It's just a pointer to a data structure in the kernel that manages all of that.  A socket with an abstract address is the same, it just doesn't have a corresponding external file.

Comment: after creating a socket (perhaps via the `socket()` function) then call `setsockopt()`   I.E.  `int enable = 1;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");`   Then the socket can be reused.  [setsockopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194961/how-do-i-use-setsockoptso-reuseaddr)

Comment: @user3629249 That doesn't work for `AF_UNIX` sockets, only TCP or UDP.