# How to force Apache HttpClient / HttpConnection to absolutely close tcp connection?

Tags: java, sockets, connection, apache-httpclient-4.x, forceclose

I use lot of http connection with Apache HttpClient (org.apache.httpcomponents 4.3.6) to test servers and I cannot force connections to close, even when I schedule `HttpConnectionManager` to `httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();` after 10 seconds in another thread.

`httpClient.close()` also doesn't help.

Connections can last for minutes or even hours.

I have tried custom `SocketConfig` and this also not helps:

```
 SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
                .setSoKeepAlive(false)
                .setSoLinger(5)
                .setSoReuseAddress(true)
                .setSoTimeout(5000)
                .setTcpNoDelay(true).build();
```

The way I am fetching the content:

```
  HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

  try (InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
       String result = IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       httpClient.close();
       return result;
  }
```

The way I am building HTTP Client:

```
    SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom()
            .setSoKeepAlive(false)
            .setSoLinger(configuration.getInt("proxy.list.socket.so.linger"))
            .setSoReuseAddress(true)
            .setSoTimeout(configuration.getInt("proxy.list.socket.so.timeout"))
            .setTcpNoDelay(true).build();

    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    builder.disableAutomaticRetries();
    builder.disableContentCompression();
    builder.disableCookieManagement();
    builder.disableRedirectHandling();
    builder.setConnectionReuseStrategy(new NoConnectionReuseStrategy());
    builder.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);
```

One of my prototypes of doing shutdown:

```
      shutdownExecutor.schedule(() -> {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            httpClient.notifyAll();
            try {
                httpClient.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }

        }, configuration.getInt("proxy.test.forced.timeout.seconds"), TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        String content = HttpContentFetcher.getAndCloseClient(url, httpClient);
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal sample? How do you attempt to close connection and why do you state it has no effect?

Comment: @Raffaele It stucks on reading response. Pasted details. Actually I;m pretty sure that I've achieved a timeout, but with length of about ~300 seconds, not 10 seconds as I want.

Comment: It is kind of bizarre that you use socket linger in your code and expect the socket to get closed immediately at the same time.

Comment: @oleg Can you provide some details? I'm not aware what thus parameter exactly mean, but I just wanted it to have KNOWN value, to be sure that it is not 0=no limit.

Comment: SO_LINGER parameter (including zero linger) and its relation to TIME_WAIT is explained reasonably well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RequestConfig` has helped. Now it looks like all the connections are discarded in specified limits.

```
       RequestConfig config= RequestConfig.custom()
                .setCircularRedirectsAllowed(false)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(4000)
                .setConnectTimeout(4000)
                .setMaxRedirects(0)
                .setRedirectsEnabled(false)
                .setSocketTimeout(4000)
                .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true).build();
        request.setConfig(config);
```