# Jersey 2 client not closing connection immediately

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

client.close(); is not closing connection to end point immediately. netstat is showing that the connection is open for couple of seconds after client.close call is completed. 
Is there a way to force close the connection immediately?

Comment: I think Jersey client uses HttpURLConnection, and I think HttpURLConnection uses persistent connections by default.  Have you tried `http.keepAlive=false`?

Answer (score -1):

This probably is due to the settings of the SO_LINGER value that defines the time between the `close()` call and the real closing of the connection.

More info about this socket option can be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required), in Java it is possible to set the value with [`Socket.setSOLinger()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger-boolean-int-).

I don't know if it is possible to set this value for Jersey, at least I cannot find something in `org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties`

Comment: SO_LINGER does not 'define the time between the `close()` call and the real closing of the connection'. It defines the time spent *in* the `close()` call waitng for pending data to be flushed. It is is usually *off*, and as a matter of fact I have never seen production code where it was set to a positive value. The true explanation of this question is that given by @BrettKail: HTTP keepalive.