# Closing sockets that haven't completed AcceptEx - if and how?

Tags: sockets, winsock, winsock2, iocp

I understand that if I issue an `AcceptEx` call, through a function pointer as recommended by the documentation, then if I specify a receiver buffer size, the call will not complete until some data is sent:

```
if (!lpfnAcceptEx(sockListen,
    sockAccept,
    PerIoData->Buffer,
    DATA_BUFSIZE - ((sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16) * 2), /* receive buffer size */
    sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16,
    sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16,
    &dwBytes,
    &(PerIoData->Overlapped)
    ))
    {
        DWORD dwLastError = GetLastError();
        // Handle error

    }
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524(v=vs.85).aspx)

> If a receive buffer is provided, the overlapped operation will not
>   complete until a connection is accepted and data is read. Use the
>   getsockopt function with the SO_CONNECT_TIME option to check whether a
>   connection has been accepted.
>
> If the socket is not connected, the getsockopt returns 0xFFFFFFFF.
>   Applications that check whether the overlapped operation has
>   completed, in combination with the SO_CONNECT_TIME option, can
>   determine that a connection has been accepted but no data has been
>   received.
>
> It is recommended such connections be terminated by closing the
>   accepted socket, which forces the AcceptEx function call to complete
>   with an error.

Now, this seems to state that I should forcibly close the socket.  However, my book "Network Programming for Microsoft Windows - Second Edition" states similar facts, but goes on to say

> As a word of warning, applications should not under any circumstances
>   close a client socket handle used in an AcceptEx call that has not
>   been accepted because it can lead to memory leaks. For performance
>   reasons, the kernel-mode structures associated with an AcceptEx call
>   will not be cleaned up when the unconnected client handle is closed
>   until a new client connection is established or until the listening
>   socket is closed.

So I'm *not* supposed to close it now??  I'm confused.

**Two questions:**

1) If a socket has not fully completed `AcceptEx`, I get back 0xFFFFFFFF from `getsockopt`.  This makes it a candidate for foribly closing.  But how am I supposed to know how long it has been sitting in this state?  I can't add my own timing logic because I don't know when the accept was made because my completion port routine hasn't completed!

2) When I figure out if I need to close the socket, how do I do it?  Is `closesocket()` enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found this out myself after examining the code posted by Len Holgate at [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2374/A-reusable-high-performance-socket-server-class).

Basically we need to store all the `SOCKET` objects (that we create in to pass to the `AcceptEx` function pointer that we obtain as shown above) in order to iterate through them.  *Programming for Microsoft Windows - Second Edition* tells us that a good time to iterate through pending connections is when we have more connections wanting to be accepted than we do outstanding `AcceptEx` calls.  We can determine if that is the case as follows:

```
WSAEVENT NewEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, TRUE, 0); // Auto reset event
WSAEventSelect(sockListen, NewEvent, FD_ACCEPT);

if (::WaitForSingleObject(NewEvent, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
     // Need to post an AcceptEx
```

Note the use of an auto-reset event, not a manual one as created by `WSACreateEvent()`.  Now, after posting the `AcceptEx`, we can loop through our pending sockets, checking the connected duration on each one:

```
// Get the time for which this socket has been connected
::getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_CONNECT_TIME, (char *)&nSeconds, &nBytes);

//
// If we decide the socket has been open for long enough, set SO_LINGER then close it
//
LINGER lingerStruct; // *
lingerStruct.l_onoff = 1;   // Leave socket open...
lingerStruct.l_linger = 0;  //...for 0 seconds after closesocket() is called

::setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char *)&lingerStruct, sizeof(lingerStruct));
closesocket(sock);
```

(*) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required) for why this is required.

The last thing to do is remove the `SOCKET` from whatever storage we are keeping it in when the `AcceptEx` call completes.

Comment: for what you need `WSAEventSelect` and events objects ? this is bad choice. not need any events and select. use only iocp.

Comment: Because how else do I know that I have more clients wanting to connect than `AcceptEx()` calls have been issued?

Comment: you can determinate for self `min` and `max` listen sockets. and begin listen with `(min+max)/2` `AcceptEx` calls. when `AcceptEx` finished - you decrement listen count. when it became `<min` on every new `AcceptEx` finished you create new socket and call `AcceptEx` on it . when client disconnect - you look for listen count - if it `<=max` - you reuse this socket and call `AcceptEx` on it again. if `>max` - you close socket. this is usual pool strategy

Answer (score 1):

> 1) If a socket has not fully completed `AcceptEx`, I get back
>   `0xFFFFFFFF` from `getsockopt`. This makes it a candidate for forcibly
>   closing.

no. this is mistake. if you get `0xFFFFFFFF` this mean that client not conect to socket. it still wait for connection. we need stop this operation, only if we decide stop listening on port at all. otherwise we not need close this socket or cancel this i/o

> But how am I supposed to know how long it has been sitting in this
>   state? I can't add my own timing logic because I don't know when the
>   accept was made because my completion port routine hasn't completed!

but `getsockopt` with `SO_CONNECT_TIME` and returns the number of seconds a socket has been connected:

so if this number is `0xFFFFFFFF` - `AcceptEx` still wait for connection and must not be closed/canceled. otherwise (we got another value) - this is number of seconds client already connected. look [example of code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606(v=vs.85).aspx)

so you can periodically check sockets - if you got *N* (`!=-1`) seconds from `getsockopt( s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_CONNECT_TIME, (char *)&seconds, (PINT)&bytes)` - this mean that client already *N* second connected to your socket but yet not send any data. exactly This (when *N* become too large) makes it a candidate for forcibly closing. but not `-1 (0xFFFFFFFF)` value.

> So I'm not supposed to close it now?? I'm confused.

you wrong understand. between the two pieces of text there is no contradiction:

> ... will not be cleaned up when the **unconnected** client handle is
>   closed ...

note that here say about closing handle used `AcceptEx`  while it still in **unconnected** state.

> It is recommended such (***connected*** but no data has been received)
>   connections be terminated by closing the accepted socket

so here say about close already **connected** socket.

so you really need close already **connected** socket, where too long no data has been received. how long (in seconds) socket connected - you got via `SO_CONNECT_TIME`

---

however from my option use receive buffer in `AcceptEx` not a good idea. better explicit call `WSARecv` after client connect. yes, this is additional call to kernel. but from another side, if you use receive buffer in `AcceptEx` - you need periodically call `getsockopt` (and this is call to kernel !) on every listen socket. so instead one call on socket, where `AcceptEx` completed - you will be need do *N* calls to `getsockopt` every *T* time period. when `AcceptEx` complete just after client connect - you can yourself save time of connection and periodically check this time yourself. but for this you not need be call to kernel and this will be much more faster. time you can get say via `GetTickCount64`

> 2) When I figure out if I need to close the socket, how do I do it? Is
>   `closesocket()` enough?

yes `closesocket()` is need and enough

Comment: Yes, you make an excellent point about the number of kernel calls.  I wanted to understand this from an academic point of view, now that I do understand it I am in a position to consider your option.  Clearly, it is the better of the two.  So thanks!