# Linux: Detecting CLOSE_WAIT on a write-only TCP socket

Tags: linux, sockets, server, freeze

I have a simple server, written in C, that accepts sensor and status information from a variety of sources, then consolidates and reformats it into a stream of ASCII text lines for clients. The clients connect via a listener socket, then read and do whatever with the stream of messages until the user closes the application. Since this is a one-way protocol, the server never bothers to check for pending received data.

Whenever there's a message to be sent to all active users, it goes through a simple loop:

```
bufflen = strlen(tcp_buff);
for (next_client_ix = 0; next_client_ix < MAX_TCP_CONNECTIONS; next_client_ix++)
    if (TCP_client_sd[next_client_ix] != 0)
        {
        rc = send(TCP_client_sd[next_client_ix], tcp_buff, bufflen, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
        if (rc != bufflen)
            {
            errno_hold = errno;
            s = inet_ntoa(Tcp_client_sin[next_client_ix].sin_addr);
            remote_port = htons(Tcp_client_sin[next_client_ix].sin_port);
            sprintf(log_buff, "Error %d (%s) sending alert to %s:%d. Closing\n", errno_hold, strerror(errno_hold), s, remote_port);
            log_message(SB_ALERT_TEXT_ERROR, log_buff);
            close(TCP_client_sd[next_client_ix]);
            TCP_client_sd[next_client_ix] = 0;        // Free the socket for the next client
            }
        }
```

This worked fine for years, on versions of Ubuntu from 10.04 through 16.04, when we typically had only 1 or 2 (occasionally 3) clients active at a time, all connected via the Ethernet LAN. Lately, we've been running more clients (still single-digit count) at a time, and most of the increase is copies of a Windows client, usually connected to the LAN via SOHO WiFi routers. This also showed up last month when we had a client connecting remotely from a conference hall with public WiFi.

Once every week or two, the server stops sending to all clients for a few minutes. When I investigate with netstat, I find one or (often) more sockets stuck in CLOSE_WAIT, with a Recv-Q of 1, and about 13K in the Send-Q. Eventually, the server spits out an error message saying it's closing a client connection due to an errno of 32 (Broken Pipe), and everything goes back to normal.

I'm *guessing* that there's some quirk in the Windows-via-WiFi connection that's causing the connection close sequence to happen differently, but that's a not-very-educated guess.

My question (finally!) is what I should do to either detect the approaching problem before it turns into a server hang, or get Linux to give me an immediate error instead of making me wait while it decides to give up. I've found a variety of ideas for servers expecting incoming data from their clients, but nothing for "write-only" connections (well, one answer was to run netstat before every write, and analyze its output, but that's not really practical for a system we hope to have feeding data from hundreds of sensor arrays to dozens of clients when it goes into full-scale production). I've tried adding some code to try to detect it using the Linux-only SIOCOUTQ fcntl looking for data piling up in the transmit queue, but haven't been able to get a good test because it happens so rarely in the wild. And my attempt to make a misbehaving client didn't go well, because client-side Linux cheerfully stacks up enough data in its receive queue to keep it from failing for several days. So the server never sees a build-up on its side.

Is there some socket or API call option I've missed that will say "Forget patience and retries: give up and fail NOW!"? Should I be patient, and wait a few weeks to see whether my SIOCOUTQ fix has solved the problem? Or do I need to refine my google keyword selection skills to find an answer that's eluded me so far?

Thanks,

Ran

Comment: I had one hang with "heaps" of CLOSE_WAIT connections, but the recent incidents had only one. Which compounds the confusion: if writing to a single "not ready for more data" socket can cause a hang, how did I manage to get 8 sockets in CLOSE_WAIT?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you aren't using non-blocking sockets or an SO_TIMEOUT.

That `send` call could hang for a long time because of a misbehaved client.  Imagine if I wrote a client that connected to your server but never called `recv` on my client socket. Literally this:

```
int result = connect(sock, addr, addrlen);
while (1) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

After a sufficient number of `send` calls to my client, the TCP pipe would get backed up, and your `send` call could literally block forever.  Hence, no other send calls other clients could take place until the previous one completed or error'd out.  Such is the nature of single-thread servers and blocking sockets.

A more likely case is if a client connects to your server, then suddenly loses network connectivity.  That could also hang your server for several seconds.

Consider any or all of the following for updating your server:

- non-blocking sockets - And handling the case where `send` returns a value indicating partial data was sent. You could also poll the socket with `recv` just to see if the remote client has exited or initiated a 1-way shutdown.
- Each client gets its own thread and message queue.  When the server has something to send, it puts a copy of the data bytes into each client's message queue. Each thread is responsible for sending.  A badly behaving client associated with one thread won't stop the other threads from sending.
- [SO_LINGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required).  You could try setting the linger time to zero on each socket to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried writing a misbehaving client just like that to test my possible fix. What I didn't realize was that the Linux it ran on has a _huge_ (multiple days' worth) limit on its receive queues, so I aborted the test rather than risk a hard server failure from the new code when I wasn't around to recover.

Comment: I think you have the right idea with changing to non-blocking sockets: the volume of data is low enough that a partial send will probably only happen in my "problem" situation anyway, so I don't need complicated recovery code. I'll give that a try. Thanks.