# when to close a socket tcp

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am working with a GPS tracker. I am listening gps tracker device through sockets. at the moment there are total 20 devices I am concurrently listening. I have few questions in mind

Initially I was opening a socket and was closing after reading it and this loop goes on. I was receiving data from the device on time. The problem was that when the devices increases, the listening time from multiple devices gets slow and it was not realtime anymore then

Then I chose not to close the socket after opening it. It became  realtime and gotten the response from each device on time but now when I checked the processes by running this command

```
 sudo netstat -tulnap | grep :8153
```

There are total 750 connections established now. So I assume I might be doing something wrong?

So I want to know is it how it should be done if I want to receive data from all the devices at a time? Or are there any better ways to implement it? If anyone can guide me to the right direction would be really appreciated.

Note: my devices could go to 20 to 20,000 devices so the solution which you provide should be able to listen data from any number of devices real-time

Thank you in advance

Comment: "Polling is evil" - avoid it, if at all possible.  Q: Why can't you just have *ONE* "listener", and have your devices periodically send an update?

Comment: I don't understand? what does it mean ? One Listener? I have one listener which is listening multiple devices.

Comment: Good: one listener, one listener socket.  DON'T leave your connections open indefinitely. Consider using UDP.

Comment: Use a library that's already designed to do this. Boost asio, for example.

Comment: @paulsm4 There is no polling here. Unclear what you mean by 'one listener'. He *has* one listener. Unclear what you're talking about. HTTP keeps connections open: why can't the OP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is:  close a socket when you're done using it; OTOH if you plan to keep receiving/sending data via that socket in the future, then keep it held open so you can do that.  When it makes sense to keep a socket open (vs closing it and then re-opening a new TCP connection later) is a judgement call that will depend on what your program is trying to accomplish.

It sounds like your program might be suffering from a "socket leak", where in some cases your program forgets to call `close()` on sockets that it no longer intends to use; and also your program keeps creating new sockets.  In that case, these open-but-forgotten sockets will build up over time, and eventually your program will run out of resources and be unable to create any more sockets.  This is a bad thing.

You don't say what language you're programming in, but if you're programming in C++, an easy way to avoid a socket-leak is to wrap each socket into a socket-holding object:

```
class SocketHolder
{
public:
   SocketHolder(int socketfd) : _fd(fd) {/* empty */}
   ~SocketHolder() {if (_fd >= 0) close(fd);}

   int GetSocketFD() const {return _fd;}

private:
   SocketHolder(const SocketHolder &);  // private and unimplemented (to prevent accidental copying of SocketHolder objects)

   int _fd;
};
```

... and then whenever you call socket()/accept()/etc to create a new socket FD, immediately hand it over to a SocketHolder object which is held by a smart-pointer, e.g.:

```
int s = socket();
std::shared_ptr<SocketHolder> holder(new SocketHolder(s));
```

... and modify your program to store and/or pass around `std::shared_ptr<SocketHolder>` objects instead of `int` socket-values.

The advantage is that once you've done this, you no longer have to remember to call `close(s)` explicitly at the appropriate time, because it will automatically be called for you when its `SocketHolder` object is deleted, and the `SocketHolder` object will be automatically deleted when the last smart-pointer referencing it goes away.  Since the `close()` call now happens without any effort on the programmer's part, a socket-leak is much less likely to occur.

Another possible source of your problem is that the OS will (by default) keep records for recently-closed TCP connections in memory for a short period even after you've closed them; doing this helps the OS ensure that any data sent to those sockets just before they were closed can get delivered, and also helps the OS avoid misinterpreting future TCP packets.  However, it does mean that TCP socket records can hang around for a brief period after the TCP socket has been closed; if that's a problem for you, you might be able to address it by setting the `SO_LINGER` socket option, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required).

If you're going to be keeping TCP connections to dozens or hundreds of devices open simultaneously, that's fine; you can do so and multiplex across them using `select()` or `poll()` or `epoll()` or `kqueue()` or similar APIs designed for handling multiple sockets at once.  In my experience, using non-blocking I/O is simpler in the long run, since it avoids the possibility that one very slow (or malfunctioning) client device might hang up your entire server.

If you really need to support thousands of simultaneous TCP connections instead of just dozens or hundreds, you might run into some scaling issues;  you might want to read [The C10K Problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html), a somewhat dated but still informative article about various approaches to handling that size of connection-load.

As paulsm4 mentioned, another alternative might be to use UDP instead of TCP for your communications.  The advantage of that is that you only need to create a single socket (which can be used to communicate with any number of devices) rather than a socket-per-device.  Some disadvantages include the fact that it's often difficult to get UDP packets routed across the Internet (firewalls tend to reject incoming UDP packets by default), and also UDP packets don't get any delivery or ordering guarantees the way TCP streams do.  Of course, if your devices speak only TCP, then UDP won't be an option for you.

Comment: Very good response: thank you.  Regarding the OP's problem: "socket leak" is definitely one possibility.  My first thought was that maybe his OS was running out of ephemeral ports.  Too many connections being opened/closed too quickly, with each connection lingering in TIME_WAIT, until all available free ports were exhausted.  In any case: all of the design alternatives you gave - including the one about SO_LINGER - are excellent suggestions :)

Comment: Hello Thank you for your great answer jeremy. I am working in PHP and I am using the library and I have no idea if that library is doing all this what you have described as I am completely new to socket programming. I am assuming you don't program in Php otherwise I would have share you the code