# How to track exact number of open connections in netty server

Tags: java, netty

I have a question about netty server monitoring. I want to see how many open connections to the server are there, so to do that we have a code that has an atomic integer counter that is increased by 1 on ChannelInitializer.initChannel(..) method and decremented by 1 in closeFuture listener for that SocketChannel channel. For some reason that I can't figure out, it doesn't go to zero and stays positive under heavy load. I was hoping that maybe there is some better way of tracking these open channels?

```
  @Override
  protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
          currentConnections.incrementAndGet();
          channel.closeFuture().addListener(f -> currentConnections.decrementAndGet());
  }
```

UPDATE:
So the number stays positive after clients stop sending traffic and disconnect.

Comment: Doesn't go to zero under heavy load? Why would you expect there to be no connections if there's a heavy load?

Comment: True, what I should say is that after heavy burst of messages, when tests stop sending new ones and clients are terminated I would expect to see 0.

Comment: It's (most likely) a TCP/IP stack related [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757289/tcp-option-so-linger-zero-when-its-required). Basically the connection isn't closed immediately, but it "lingers" for a while. It's normal, and unless it's causing you problems (running out of resources), there's no need to touch it.

Comment: That would be a good explanation, but the number seem to never go down.

Comment: Well is there a reason why you need it to go down? Why are you tracking it? Do you have a problem, or are you just expecting it to behave in a certain way?

Comment: To understand the state of the system really, monitoring and alerting, how many open connections are seems like a reasonable metric to have.

Comment: It might be, I don't know Netty internals well enough to say. But looks like the maintainers [aren't really sure either](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/4981), although there's some [recent interest](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/8680).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a `ChannelInboundHandler` and override the `channelRegistered` and `channelUnregistered` like so:

```
  @Override
  public void channelRegistered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    if (ctx.channel().remoteAddress() != null) {
      connections.inc();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void channelUnregistered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    currentConnections.dec();
  }
```

Another way is to only add the channel to a `ChannelGroup` when it's registered, and use `ChannelGroup#size` when you want to query the current connection count.

I guess the former incurs less overhead, but the later allows you to performs actions on all active channels if you need this sort of functionality anyway.

Comment: Cheers, what would be the advantage of using channelRegistered/Unregistered over channelActive/Inactive?

Comment: Also should that remoteAddress check be also present in the channelUnregistered method so the counter wouldn't go into negative range? Or there is something going on that it's not required?

Comment: Strictly speaking, according to the netty-in-action book I think it is more "correct" to use the active/inactive states if you want to monitor connected clients. I use the registered/unregistered as it represents the entire channel life-cycle which represents the resources you're holding more correctly. I guess both events will work for you

Comment: The channel that lacks the remote address is the parent channel - it's not a representation of one of the inbound "connections". Maybe Norman Maurer can explain this better...